# Hibernate object Serialization

Tags: hibernate

Why a Hibernate persistence object in Java is marked serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because almost always your data objects crosses the machine that contains your data access code.
So your objects should be serialized here and deserialized in distant machine to be used.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Java Persistence with Hibernate:

> Hibernate doesn’t require that
>   persistent classes implement
>   Serializable. However, when objects
>   are stored in an HttpSession or passed
>   by value using RMI, serialization is
>   necessary. (This is likely to happen
>   in a Hibernate application.)